# Ajax live insertion double submit glitch

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This code is a savings system. But the withdrawal is not finished yet because i've found a glitch in my code. This code works fine. It can validate properly and deposite properly. And i found the glitch after I accidentally press the enter twice. And i noticed that i inserted two records in the database before clearing the password of the cashier. I want is even the cashier pressed the enter twiced.It's just insert one record in the transaction table.

this is my SavingsAddInsert.php

```
    <?php
include("general.php");

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $Amount = $_POST['Amount'];
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];
        $Transaction = $_POST['Transaction'];
        $SaverAccount = $_POST['AccountID'];


        if(empty($Amount) && empty($Password) && $Transaction == "undefined"){
            $error[] = "Please Select Transaction Type and put an Amount and Password!";
        }else{
            if(empty($Amount) === true || $Amount === null){
                $error[] = "Amount is empty";
            }else{
                if(!preg_match('/^[0-9.]*$/',$Amount)){
                    $error[] = "i only accept numeric and decimal";
                }
            }
            if(empty($Password) === true || $Password === null){
                $error[] = "Password is empty";
            }else{
                $Cashier_Password = Cashier_password($_SESSION['AccountID'],$Password);
                if($Cashier_Password === false){
                    $error[] = "Cashier Password is wrong";
                }
            }

            if($Transaction == "undefined"){
                $error[] = "Please select Category in Transaction Type ";
            }else{
                if($Transaction == "WITHDRAW"){
                    if($Amount > Check_Balance($SaverAccount)){
                        $error[] = "Insufficient Balance!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(isset($error)){
            echo output_errors($error);
        }


        if(empty($error) || $error = 0){
            if($Transaction == "DEPOSITE"){//deposite
                $Balance = Check_Balance($SaverAccount);
                $TotalAmount = $Balance + $Amount;
                $Cashier = $_SESSION['AccountID'];
                $SavingsID = Get_SavingsID($SaverAccount);

                $update_savings = mysql_query("UPDATE tblsavings SET TotalSavings = '$TotalAmount' WHERE AccountID = '$SaverAccount'");

                if($update_savings){

                    $insert_transaction = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbltransaction 
                                                                    (SavingsID,Cashier,ReceiveWithdraw,RunningBalance,TransactionType,Date,Time) VALUES
                                                                    ('$SavingsID','$Cashier','$Amount','$TotalAmount','$Transaction',now(),now())") or die(mysql_error());

                        if($insert_transaction){
                            echo "<p><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i>Transaction Complete. The Total Amount of AccountNo:'".get_AccountNo($SaverAccount)."' is ".$TotalAmount."</p>";

                        }
                }
            }
            else if($Transaction == "WITHDRAW"){//withdraw
                unset($Password);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

this is my SavingsAdd.php

```
<div class="popup-wrapper">
        <div class="popup-body">
            <div class="popup-head">
                <p>Withdraw and Deposite</p>
            </div>
            <?php 
                if(isset($_GET['Account'])){
                    $Account = $_GET['Account'];
                    $get_info1 = mysql_query("SELECT tbluserdetail.FirstName,
                                                        tbluserdetail.MiddleName,
                                                        tbluserdetail.LastName,
                                                        tbluserdetail.Image,
                                                        tbluserdetail.ImageName,
                                                        tbluserdetail.Gender,
                                                        useraccounts.AccountNo,
                                                        useraccounts.AccountID,
                                                        useraccounts.Position
                                                        FROM useraccounts 
                                                        INNER JOIN tbluserdetail
                                                        ON useraccounts.UserID=tbluserdetail.UserID
                                                        WHERE useraccounts.AccountID = '$Account'");

                while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($get_info1)){
                    $FirstName_p = $row1['FirstName'];
                    $MiddleName_p = $row1['MiddleName'];
                    $LastName_p = $row1['LastName'];
                    $AccountNo_p = $row1['AccountNo'];
                    $AccountID_p = $row1['AccountID'];
                    $Gender_p = $row1['Gender'];
                    $Image_p = $row1['Image'];
            ?>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="p-header col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                        <?php
                            if(empty($Image_p)){
                                if($Gender_p == "Male"){
                                    echo '<img src="img/default-male.jpg"/>';
                                }else if($Gender_p == "Female"){
                                    echo '<img src="img/default-female.jpg"/>';
                                }               
                            }else{
                                    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $Image_p ).'"/>';
                            }

                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-info col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p><?php if(isset($_GET['Account'])){ echo $FirstName_p." ".$MiddleName_p." ".$LastName_p;} ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <p>Account No: <?php if(isset($_GET['Account'])){ echo $AccountNo_p;} ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div id="ajaxResult">
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                        <p>Transaction Type:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                        <select class="form-control" name="Transaction">
                            <option value="undefined">Select</option>
                            <option value="WITHDRAW">Withdraw</option>
                            <option value="DEPOSITE">Deposite</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                        <p>Amount:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount" id="Amount" placeholder="0.00"/>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="AccountID" id="AccountID" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['Account'])){ echo $AccountID_p;} ?>" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                        <p>Cashier password:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="••••••••••"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="float-right col-md-12">
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }}?>
        </div>
   </div>
```

and this is my javascript inside the SavingsAdd.php

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("myForm");
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

      var oOutput = document.getElementById("ajaxResult"),
          fn = new FormData(form);


      fn.append("Submit", fn.get('Submit'));
      fn.append("Amount", fn.get('Amount'));
      fn.append("AccountID", fn.get('AccountID'));
      fn.append("Password", fn.get('Password'));
      fn.append("Transaction", fn.get('Transaction'));

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'SavingAddInsert.php', true);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                if(form){
                    document.getElementById('Amount').value = null;
                    document.getElementById('Password').value = null;
                    var return_data = xhr.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("ajaxResult").innerHTML = return_data;
                }



            }
        }
      xhr.send(fn);
      ev.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

[image: as]

as you can see in the image. i try to submit by pressing double enter. and the record inserted it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You reset the passwort input field only after you receive a response from the server. You need to do this directly after you send the request.

If you want to keep the data (including passwort) in case the request fails, you need to add a variable stating if a request is active (and waiting). Set this to 1 or 'active' instead of emptying the password field and reset after the request was successful. As long as a request is active, your JS must not send another request.